# How Can I Print The Help Description Of "__main__" In Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, interpreter

With imported modules, calling `help(<module_name>)` in the interpreter will print the description of a module; usually, this is a docstring, but if the module begins with comments it will pass those as a description. In a script that is not imported (ie, anything with a `__name__` of `__main__`), calling `print(__doc__)` will give a similar result—but only if there is a docstring; it won't pull any comments like `help()` does.

So how can I call `help()` on a script itself and get the description, particularly if there is no docstring proper but only comments?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the fact that the module is available as `sys.modules['__main__']`:

```
"""
Is this what you want?
"""
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    help(sys.modules['__main__'])
```

outputs

```
Help on module __main__:

NAME
    __main__ - Is this what you want?

DATA
    __annotations__ = {}

FILE
    /Users/akx/Desktop/so61453557.py

(END)
```

Or, for a file that has no docstring, but has comments:

```
# This is
# the description
# and not even a haiku

import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    help(sys.modules['__main__'])
```

```
Help on module __main__:

NAME
    __main__

DESCRIPTION
    # This is
    # the description
    # and not even a haiku

DATA
    __annotations__ = {}

FILE
    /Users/akx/Desktop/so61453557.py

(END)
```

## EDIT

Okay, this turned out more interesting than I thought, and a delve into CPython internals!

`python -i so61453557.py` and `python -m so61453557` act differently here.

The former calls `pymain_run_file()`, which calls `PyRun_AnyFileExFlags()`, which calls `PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags()`. As far as I can tell, it basically synthesizes a `__main__` module and evaluates the file in that context using `PyRun_FileExFlags`.

The latter calls `pymain_run_module()`, whose real logic is contained in the stdlib `runpy.py` module (`_run_module_as_main`).

After that,

When `-i` is set (`interactive`, `inspect`), `pymain_repl()` is called, which may call an interactive hook if set (e.g. readline completion and stuff), and then calls `PyRun_AnyFileFlags(stdin, "<stdin>", cf)`.

I don't know what's cleaning out `__main__` after the file is run (it could be the `XDECREF()` at the end of `PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags`), but here're some conclusions.

- `python -i -m so61453557` seems to retain `__main__` (`<module '__main__' from 'so61453557.py'>`), so you can run `help(sys.modules['__main__'])` as you expect in the REPL.
- `python -i so61453557.py`: when entering the REPL the `__main__` module is reverted to `<module '__main__' (<_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x10fb2e990>)>`.
- `python` has a third version of `__main__`: `<module '__main__' (built-in)>`.

As a hack, I thought one could `sys.modules['hack'] = sys.modules['__main__']`, but that doesn't work; the module itself is being changed, and module objects can't be pickled, so you can't assign `copy.copy(main)` either.

But, **TL;DR:** This works if you use `python -i -m something`, it doesn't if you do `python -i something.py`.

Comment: This does not provide the Description field but rather returns the same information as `"""print(__doc__)"""`.

Comment: @JBT Added an edit. It does what `help()` would do (... since it _is_ `help()`).

Comment: It does not work in the interpreter, however, which remains my issue. Try running `"""help(sys.modules['__main__'])"""` again from the shell—the description disappears!

Comment: You mean that if I start the Python REPL and do that? Sure, there _is_ no `__main__` (or rather, it's an empty built-in dummy module). What should it show?

Comment: I am staying in the shell after the script completes. It is clearly still in the script, because it continues to list all variables, classes, and functions in help output and I can still call anything I've defined. But the description? Gone.

Comment: @JBT Can you please give an example file and reproduction steps in your original question, then?

Comment: I am using your code verbatim, saved as help.py . I am running from cmd in interactive mode: `"""python -i help.py"""`.

Comment: So is your actual use case that you'd need to see the `help()` of a module you've run via command line using the `-i` flag?

Comment: Correct. As noted in my question, I need to be able to call `"""help()"""` on the script itself, from the interpreter, and get a full description—even if there is no docstring.

Comment: @JBT Okay, I dug in a little deeper, see my edit :)

Comment: Excellent detective work! It turns out that when I run scripts with `"""python -i -m"""`, I don't even need to import the sys module—I can call `"""help(__name__)"""` directly, as I had hoped for. Changing all my keyboard shortcuts now and hoping for no side-effects...